# Webpage not returning my app's name when I load it. It leaves it blank. (Laravel)

Tags: php, html, laravel, environment-variables

I have tried to change the name of my app from Laravel to something else, but I just can't get it to work!

This is the `.env` file:

```
APP_NAME=
APP_ENV=local
```

This is the `config.app.name` line:

```
 'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Pet Me'),
```

This is the code in my `layouts.app` file, which is my main layout file:

```
<title>{{ config('app.name', 'Pet Me') }}</title>
```

And this is what I am getting when inspecting the webpage I load on Chrome. It just isn't registering my name.

```
<title></title>
```

Can someone help me?

I have tried running this on my console, but it didn't work:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the `APP_NAME` to an empty string, `""`; it will use that. You should comment out the line `APP_NAME` in the `.env` file if you want the default, the second argument to `env()`, in the config file to be used.

Comment: Well, I'm dumb. Thank you, this fixed it!